# php mysql+ Notice: Array to string conversion in C

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, explode

I keep getting this error when I try to explode the array by a comma, How to fix this error can anyone help me ???

## friend_request.php

```
 <?php

     if(isset($_POST['acceptrequest'.$user_from]))
     {
         //select the friend array  row  from the logged in user
         $get_friend_check = mysql_query("SELECT friend_array FROM user WHERE user_name = '$login_user'") or die(mysql_error());
         $get_friend_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_friend_check);
         $friend_array = $get_friend_row['friend_array'];
         $friendArray_explode = explode(",", $friend_array);
         echo $friendArray_explode;
     }
     ?>

The last line of code produce this error how to fix it ??
```

Comment: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Answer (score 1):

This is a *NOTICE* (not an error!) - you're trying to print an array as if it was a string. Use `print_r` or `var_dump` instead of `echo`:

```
print_r($friendArray_explode);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are trying to pinrt an array as it was a string only using echo. For arrays you can use both `print_r` or `var_dump`

I would also sugeest you to stop using  `mysql_` api since they are depecrated, please switch to [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Furthermore you are ready to `mysql injection`. there is a nice tutorial here which explain you everything about that -> [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)